# LIGO detection statistic, SNR formula

Tags: experimental-physics, gravitational-waves, statistics, ligo, noise

According to B. P. Abbott paper published in Physical Review Letters, "Observation of Gravitational Waves from a Binary Black Hole Merger"

http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102

they are computing SNR (signal-noise relation) by the following formula:

$$
\eta_c = \sqrt{\frac{2E_c}{(1+E_n/E_c)}}
$$
where $E_c$ is the dimensionless coherent signal energy obtained by cross-correlating the two reconstructed waveforms, and $E_n$ is the dimensionless residual noise energy after the reconstructed signal is
subtracted from the data.

I just would like someone could shed some light about this formula, how do they get it?, where it cames from?

I am interested in analyzing the LIGO SNR in detail and find myself kinda stuck due to this "detection statistic" formula.

Thanks in advance, best regards.